# Once JavaScript Function ends, the website restarts

Tags: javascript, html, function, web

I have a function perform its task but then the whole website just refreshes once it ends.  However, the program should continue to go after the program ends.  Can someone please help me fix the code so I can add left point, right point, and all the other points.

```html
<!--
Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Path It Your Way: Creating Buildings</title>
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Seven Theme Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
 Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
 <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!---- start-smoth-scrolling---->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script>
    // $(document).ready(function(){
    //     $("#buildingNameSubmit").click(function(){
    //         $("#room").fadeIn("slow");
    //         $("#building").fadeOut();
    //     });
    // });
    </script> -->
  <!---- start-smoth-scrolling---->


</head>
<body>
<!--body-->
<div id="home" class="top-header"> 
     <div class="container">
   <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/rsz_banner.png" alt="" /></a>
   </div>     
   <div class="top-menu">
    <span class="menu"></span>       
    <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="enterdata.html">ENTER BUILDING</a></li>
     <li><a class="scroll" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
     <li><a class="scroll" href="navigate.html">NAVIGATE BUILDING</a></li>
     </ul>      
   </div> 
   <div class="clearfix"> </div> 
    <!-- script-for-menu -->
   <script>
    $("span.menu").click(function(){
     $(".top-menu ul").slideToggle("slow" , function(){
     });
    });
   </script>
   <!-- script-for-menu -->
   
  </div>
</div>
<!--banner/-->
<div class="single">
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Creating Navigation Data</h2>
  <div class="single-section">
   <div class="single-pic">
    <img src="images/keyboard.jpg" alt="Source: http://www.p-s.co.nz/images/keyboard.jpg"/>
   </div>

 <div class="content-form">
  <form name="coordinatesSubmit">       
   <div id="buildingDiv">       
      <h3>How to Enter a Building</h3>
      <p>In the following text input, please type the name of the building you are creating a navagation system for.  After you type in the name of the building, please click the Submit Building Name button.</p>
    <h3>Enter Building Name</h3>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <input type="text" id="buildingName" class="form-control bubbleInfo2" placeholder="Building Name" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <center><input type="button" class="buttonForm" id="buildingNameSubmit" onClick="buildStart()" value="Submit Building Name"/>
       </div>       
    </div>
            </div>
   <div id="roomDiv">   
   <h3>How to Enter a Room</h3>
      <p>In the form below, please click if your room has corners or not.  If your room does not have corners, please select the Rounded Room button.  If you did not click Rounded Room, please start with the first point, which you should start by clicking first point on the left side of your door and continue by clicking next point on the right side of the door.  Continue clicking next point for every corner in the room in clockwise direction.  However if your room is a circle, please click first point at the left side of the door and then click next point at the right side of the door and submit the room.  Everytime you click submit room, please MAKE SURE you enter a room name!!</p>
      <br>
      <br>
       <h3>Enter Room</h3> 
          <select id="selectOpt" onChange="wValue(this.value)">
                    <option disabled selected>Please Choose</option>
                    <option value="1">Cornered Room</option>
                    <option value="2">Rounded Room</option>
                </select>
       <div id="buttons" class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="leftButton">
              <button id="whichButtonLeft" onClick="wPoint('left')" class="btn btn-inverse bubbleInfo">Left Side of Door</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="rightButton">
              <button id="whichButtonRight" onClick="wPoint('right')" class="btn btn-inverse bubbleInfo">Right Side of Door</button>
          </div>            
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="pointButton">
              <button id="whichButtonPoint" onClick="wPoint()" class="btn btn-inverse bubbleInfo">Add Point</button>
          </div>                        
           <br>    
           <br>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" id="roomName" class="form-control bubbleInfo2" placeholder="Room Name" />
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
           <center><input type="button" id="roomSubmit" class="buttonForm" onClick="submit()" value="Submit Room"/>
          </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
           <center><input type="button" id="roomSubmit" class="buttonForm" onClick="submit()" value="Submit Room & Add New Room"/>
          </div>        
       </div>
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
    </div>
      </form>
   </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#roomDiv').hide();
            $('#buildingNameSubmit').click(function() {
                    $('#roomDiv').show();
                    $('#buildingDiv').hide();
            });
        });
        </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#buttons').hide();
            $('#selectOpt').change(function() {
                $('#buttons').show();
                $('#selectOpt').hide();
            });
        });
        </script>   
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#whichButtonRight').hide();
            $('#whichButtonPoint').hide();            
            $('#whichButtonLeft').click(function() {
                $('#whichButtonRight').show();
                $('#whichButtonLeft').hide();
            });
            $('#whichButtonRight').click(function() {
                $('#whichButtonPoint').show();
                $('#whichButtonRight').hide();
            });            
        });
        </script>  
    <script>
    
    var serial;
    var turn = 0;
    
    // Serial Script
    function buildStart() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    }
    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
    function success(pos) {
        var crd = pos.coords;
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        // serial is 17 digits long
        serial = crd.latitude.toString().substring(4, 6) + "" + crd.longitude.toString().substring(4, 6) + "" + n;
        buildingSubmit();
    };
    function error(err) {
      alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    };
    // Serial Finished
    
    
    var str = "";


    // Building Name and Serial Concat
    function buildingSubmit() {
        str = serial + ">" + document.getElementById('buildingName').value;
        alert(str);
        // document.getElementById('roomDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
        // document.getElementById('buildingDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    // Building Name Finished
    
    
    // Type of Room
    function wValue(value) {
        if (value == 1) {
            str = str + "#" + "norm";
        } else {
            str = str + "#" + "round";            
        }
    }
    // Room Type Finished

    var temp = "";    
    var times = 0;
    
    //Add Point to Room
    function wPoint(buttonNum) {
        if (buttonNum == "left") {
            alert(buttonNum);
            str = str + "doorLeft";
            addCoordinates();
            times = times + 1;
            alert(str);
            document.getElementById('whichButtonLeft').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            if (times == 2) {
                document.getElementById('whichButtonPoint').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        } else if (buttonNum == "right") {
            alert(buttonNum);
            str = str + "doorRight";
            times = times + 1;
            document.getElementById('whichButtonRight').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            if (times == 2) {
                document.getElementById('whichButtonPoint').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        } else {
            
        }
    }
        
        
        function addCoordinates() {
            alert("working");
            getLocation();
        }
            
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {                
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
            }
        }
                
        function showPosition(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            var alt = position.coords.altitude;
            temp = lat + "/" + lon + "/" + alt;
            playCoordinates();
        }
            
        function playCoordinates() {
            alert(temp);   
            str = str + temp;
            alert(str);
        }

        function getLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else {
                    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have so many `document.ready()` definitions ? Can't you club them all ? I think you're just clicking on a button which is submitting the form, which will naturally refresh the page. If you don't want your page to refresh, but still need to send some data to server, you can fire an Ajax call on click of that button

Comment: I need to have four different values within the form at different times in order to submit the form.

Comment: But those document.ready() callback's are invoked one after the other just in the order you defined in your page, they don't do anything special, so I think you can just club them all in to a single function

Comment: Also, I'd move the inline onclick handlers into you main JS - it's just confusing matters.

Comment: How do you do element.click function @TonyMerryfield

Comment: I've added more detailed l below using an example from your page.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess here because im on my mobile and there is sooo much code.

Sounds like you are using click() on anchor elements or similar? If so then you need to add preventDefault() inside that function.

```
element.click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* rest of code here */
});
```

So something like this - where it looks like you're submitting something, change this:

```
$('#buildingNameSubmit').click(function(event) {
        $('#roomDiv').show();
        $('#buildingDiv').hide();
});
```

To:

```
$('#buildingNameSubmit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#roomDiv').show();
        $('#buildingDiv').hide();
});
```

Like I said, just off the top of my head.

Comment: can you use an example please, I'm kind of confused @Tony-Merryfield

Comment: I've added extra detail above - as I say, I'm on my phone so I might be waaaay off on this, but it sounds right based on what your seeing.

Comment: When you view your console, are there any errors as you use the page?